# Como abrir localmente si uso listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)

Tags: javascript, html, heroku

estoy usando heroku para implementar un proyecto. Funciona bien en heroku, pero cuando quiero verlo localmente no me abre.

Para que funcione en Heroku usé: listen(process.env.PORT || 5000) y borré:

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log("consoling on port 3000");
})
```

Cómo debería abrir el proyecto localmente? Es porque todavía me faltan corregir cosas y quiero verlas rápido y para ver los cambios en Heroku tengo que hacer varios pasos (o eso creo).

Comment: ¿Probaste ingresando a http://localhost:3000 ?

Comment: Trabajaba bien en localhost:3000 hasta que hice ese cambio y ahora no funciona ahí.

Comment: prueba con el *localhost:5000* ya que según veo si no esta definida la variable de entorno entonces usa el puerto 5000 `process.env.PORT || 5000`

Comment: Entendí mal, creía que habías borrado 5000 y puesto 3000. El comentario de @AndresAranda es acertado.

Comment: tenes que hacer un archivo .env en la raiz del proyecto, donde pongas PORT=3000 (el arhivo es .env solamente, sin nombre)

Comment: Hola @MarceloZárate ya probé con http://localhost:5000/ y tampoco. En VS Code abajo a la derecha veo que dice Port: 5500, probé con ese y tampoco.

Comment: @FacundoE.Villagra creé el archivo .env, solo debería poner PORT=3000 o algo más?

Comment: Realmente deberías editar tu pregunta y compartir más código y los errores que te muestra, de otro modo se nos hace difícil ayudar.

Comment: Entiendo, pero el error que me tira en Chrome es simplemente "La página localhost ha rechazado la conexión." Y creo que la única parte del código que influye es la del listen, por eso contaba que estaba usando: .listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)   No sé qué más podría explicar. Si uso http://localhost:5500/ en Chrome me aparece el directorio con todas las carpetas del proyectos.